# solutions of two quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Suppose that $\alpha$ and  $\alpha'$ are two negative real numbers.
Consider the following two equations

(1) $b^2=b\alpha'+\alpha$

(2) $b^2\alpha'+b\alpha=1$

Find the number the solutions of the two equations with $b\in \mathbb C$.

The equation (2) implies that $b(b\alpha'+\alpha)=1$.
And replacing  the equation (1) we have that
$$b^3=1.$$

This implies that  the cube roots of unity are the only possible solutions. Note that $b=1$ is impossible, because $\alpha,\alpha'$ are negative.

The cube roots of unity are they possible solutions or are there more possible solutions?

How are these types of equations solved?

Thanks you all.

Comment: why? i dont understand,  could you explain please?

Comment: You forgot to factor $b$ from the second term.

Comment: You get $b(b\alpha'+\alpha)=1$

Comment: That is just a typo though. The answer is yes, since you found that $b^3=1$ you can just substitute all possible solutions for $b$ (namely the cube roots of unity) and see if you get something that works for the alphas. The cube roots of unity are the only possible solutions for b

Comment: and the  cube roots of unity are the only possible solutions?

Comment: The only possible values for $b$ yes!

Comment: Since you saw that if you find $\alpha, \alpha',\beta$ that satisfy your equation, then $b^3=1$ has to hold.

Comment: but, the first equation we have two solutions and the second two solutions, then, the number of possible solutions is four?

Comment: You have to determine, for each *candidate* value of $~b,~$ the set of all satisfying ordered pairs $~\left( ~a,a^\prime ~\right).$

Comment: Yes, indeed but that should be light work since $\alpha,\alpha'$ have to be negative numbers, you can just use polar coordinates and that should solve the problem for $(\alpha,\alpha')$

Comment: Also note that the second equation will not give anymore info, since you already used it for $b^3=1$, so you can just omit it for finding $(\alpha,\alpha')$

Answer (score 3):

Let $w=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Then the cube roots of unity are $1,w,w^2$, and one also has $1+w+w^2=0$. From your computations it follows that $b$ cannot be 1. So it is either $w$ or $w^2$. First we will consider (1).
If $b=w$, then $w^2=w\alpha'+\alpha$, i.e., $(\alpha'+1)w+(\alpha+1)=0$, which is only possible if $\alpha'=\alpha=-1$. Similarly, one can see that $b=w^2$ is a solution for (1) if $\alpha'=\alpha=-1$.
Exactly the same way one treats (2) by considering the possibilities $b=w,w^2$. If one wants a common solution to (1) and (2), then one only obtains that if $\alpha'=\alpha=-1$, and in that case both $b=w$ and $w^2$ is a solution.

Comment: What happens if the value of $b^2$ en (1) is replacing in (2) ? 
In this case we have the following: $(b\alpha'+\alpha)\alpha'+b\alpha=1$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I edit my question